# Copying all files from a directory using a pig command

Tags: apache-pig, hdfs, bigdata

Hey I need to copy all files from a local directory to the `HDFS` using `pig`.

In the pig script I am using the `copyFromLocal` command with a wildcard in the source-path

> i.e copyFromLocal /home/hive/Sample/* /user
>
> It says the source path doesnt exist.

When I use `copyFromLocal /home/hive/Sample/ /user` , it makes another directory in the HDFS by the name of 'Sample', which I don't need.

But when I include the file name i.e `/home/hive/Sample/sample_1.txt` it works.

I dont need a single file. I need to copy all the files in the directory without making a directory in the HDFS.

PS: Ive also tried *.txt, ?,?.txt
No wildcards work.

Comment: colud you please add the copy script that you tired to your question. so that we can get clear picture on what's the issue ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pig copyFromLocal/toLocal commands work only for a file or a directory.It will never take series of files (or) wildcard.More over, pig concentrates on processing data from/to HDFS.Upto my knowledge you cant even loop the files in a directory with ls.because it lists out files in HDFS. So, for this scenario I would suggest you to write a shell script/action(i.e. fs command) to copy files from locally to HDFS.

check this link below for info: 
http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#copyFromLocal

Comment: Above link is no longer valid. Please check and update this for future references. Thanks.